# How to calculate the angle of a vector $x\hat i + y\hat j$ if $x = 0$

Tags: vectors

I understand that to determine the direction for a vector you use the equation $$\theta = \arctan{\bigg(\frac{y}{x}\bigg)}$$ and I understand that x correlates with  $\hat{i}$, but what if $x=0$? As in the case of $$\vec b = 0\hat{i}+ 3\hat{j}.$$

How would one determine the direction of $\vec b$?

Comment: It is **not** $\hat{i}=0$ (we know $\hat{i}$ and we know it is not the zero vector), it's the *coefficient* of $\hat{i}$ being zero.

Comment: There is an answer below. The purpose of my comment was to point out that you **can't** say $\hat{i}=0$ under any circumstance. So, please, edit accordingly.

Comment: ***DON'T*** do that.

Comment: @Alizai, please do **not** edit out the question, especially after it has been answered. It may be helpful to other users.

Comment: Once you have posted a question (or answer) here, you have licensed its content to Stack Exchange, and it may be presented here in whatever manner we deem best. As you've ignored the community thus far, this question is now temporarily locked in its current state.

Answer (score 6):

As you suggest, $\arctan(y/x)$ is a way to find the direction only in certain directions. But the first principles approach is to think geometrically about where the vector lies and use appropriate formula for angles in different quadrants or in the direction of coordinate axes.

For the vector you cite, the angular direction is clearly $\pi/2$, where we take the direction to be in the interval $[0,2\pi)$ or $(-\pi,\pi]$.

This issue comes up in computer programing and the awkwardness of using different inverse trig functions for different quadrants has a work around. The name for a function that deals with all directions in several languages is `ATAN2(y,x)`. If you are programming, check the documentation for your language.

Comment: You could also use $\operatorname{arccotan}(x/y)$. That solves the problem neatly.

Comment: @Arthur (not Fischer) Yes. But the larger point is we need to use a different inverse trig function depending on the direction.